# Macro in Adobe Photoshop for consecutive numbers

Tags: script, adobe-photoshop, automation, macros, photoshop-cs6

I want to have a way where the numbers of a thumbnail image will automatically run itself from one to 300 and save each individual image as a .png file (a macro/automation/script).

For example, I want to have a thumbnail like this:

[image]

Then, after a while:

[image]

Basically, every consecutive number from 1 to 300. Also, something that would be nice is to have a way to select the start and stop numbers (instead of 1 to 300, say, 1 to 9, because two digit numbers will need the image to be adjusted).

Is there any possible way to do this (even with external programs)? If so, how could it be done?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is possible using the built-in "actions" macro feature of PS. It is *certainly* possible with the [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) which has complete programming support natively.

However, have you tried using something like [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to generate a keyboard and/or mouse macro? It certainly has the logic and variable capabilities, you'd just need to make sure that you can control PS properly. I've done this with numerous applications in the past but not with PS.

UPDATE:
Given your problems with windows not aligning, the only way AHK macros would work for you would be if everything can be done via keyboard. Though I assume that you noted the mouse control is relative to the parent window?

In GIMP, you can do macros using "script-fu", macros are written in a language called "scheme" though There are a number of sites with many examples. [Here](http://gimpscripts.com/) for example. If you need to go further, you can write your own plugins using Python. The [GIMP documentation site](http://www.gimp.org/docs/) has some details. Again there are plenty of sites with examples. Have a go and perhaps raise a new, more specific question as you get stuck ;)

For Photoshop, [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html) is the reference I missed last time. Thanks to Alan for pointing it out, it's been a long time since I last used Photoshop.

Comment: Photoshop supports scripting in VBScript, Applescript, or JavaScript, so you could program things in there as well.

Comment: Thanks Alan, I missed that on their web site, very useful to know.

Comment: Julian Knight, I've tried AutoHotKey but the windows don't always align, and each set of thumbnails is different, so the mouse clicks are usually off from the programming time; it didn't work for me (looking for something inside Photoshop, if that's possible). I like that it could be done in GIMP  but how? Is there a program/add-on/way to do it on that?
@AlanShutko How is this possible, with the different scripts? Is there an option in Photoshop that allows for these scripts to run?